# How to animate the opacity of android gridLayout?

Tags: android, animation, zooming, image, android-gridlayout

Actually, I got a little problem while building my Android App. I want to create a mini-game in my app. It will works like this:

- At the begining an image appears
- then the app ask the user to zoom-in the picture
- then a grid will appear and seperate the picture into pixels (like the one million pixel wall for example)
- the user will have to choose one "pixel" of the grid and he will win (or not) some points.

It seems quite simple but i got some issues:

- How can i create this grid? (GridLayout? )
- How can i put an invisible Grid (opacity=0) on a picture ? (Grid Layout Option Maybe ? )
- How can i use the zoom-in option to be as smooth(natural and simple) as possible?
- What should i do in order to turn the  Grid opacity to 1 when "the Zoom in" effect has been done ?

I know that some several questions are likely answering to the grid problem but I need some personal advices in order to build my own game. General tips and tricks are welcomed. Explanations will be great.

Thanks in advance.

P.S.: Sorry for my English. It's not really my main language but I hope that I am still understandable.

Comment: You might want to convert this to a wiki because the question title doesn't encompass the actual question being asked - and the question itself is more of the "how can this be done" variety (opinions abound) instead of the "why isn't this working" variety.

Comment: Oh ok, my bad, i'm new here so thanks for pointing this out .I'm actually looking for a way to make a wiki.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i've found The GridLayout.setalpha(alpha) Option so i know now how to build a grid and to manipulate his opacity.
 I just Need now some informations about how to animate this grid with the zoom-in effect and the Zoom-out effect !